# how to get Activity's windowToken without view?

Tags: android, android-activity

Now, I try to hide the softkeyboard when user touch outside the keyboard:

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editView.getWindowToken(),
InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

I want put the logic in my base activity class, so if it is possible to getWindowToken without View?

Comment: is this a typos "getgetWindowToken()"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to hide soft keyboard on android after clicking outside EditText?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext)

Comment: `InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);`

`inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(findViewById(android.R.id.content).getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Surely you can use:

```
getContentView().getWindowToken()
```

or you can refer to [SO Quest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785558/find-the-window-containing-a-view-in-android/2816319#2816319)

Comment: Solved according Hanry's suggestion: findViewById(android.R.id.content).getWindowToken()

Comment: There is no getContentView() method. Use findViewById(android.R.id.content).getWindowToken() instead.

Answer (score 50):

I faced exactly the same problem, while writing `OnPageChangeListener` within an Activity. You can use one of these solutions. Either:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getWindowToken()
```

or:

```
findViewById(android.R.id.content).getWind‌​owToken()
```

Answer (score 8):

**Simply** use `getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken()`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final String M_TOKEN = "mToken";

@Nullable
protected IBinder getToken(Activity activity) {
    try {
        Field mTokenField = Activity.class.getDeclaredField(M_TOKEN);
        mTokenField.setAccessible(true);
        IBinder mToken = (IBinder) mTokenField.get(activity);
        return mToken;
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        // handle 
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
       // handle
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just get the token from the `WindowManager.LayoutParams` of the window directly

```
getWindow().getAttributes().token
```

Comment: From the docs `This will usually be filled in for you.`. This is strange :)

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin:

```
val imm  = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(window.attributes.token, 0)
```

Or, If you have a view:

```
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on your manifest file activity tag to hide keyboard.

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```