# Android:Hide keyboard after button click

Tags: java, android, keyboard, hide

I need to hide the android keyboard after a button click.

I have seen many examples of how to do this, however, they all appear to use a specific editText object.

e.g.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

My problem is that I am building the screen dynamically, thus there could be mane edit text fields. Is there a way the keyboard can be hidden without me having to specify which editText object I am hiding it for.

Comment: You can hide it for the whole Activity, this sums it up nicely:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789514/how-to-get-activitys-windowtoken-without-view

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You could instead set it to your layout, ie:

```
LinearLayout mainLayout;

// Get your layout set up, this is just an example
mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);

// Then just use the following:
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mainLayout.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

This is an example assuming that your layout will be created regardless of how many `EditText` objects (or other objects) are placed on it.

Edit: Also, something I find very useful is to make sure that the keyboard is hidden when an activity first launches (ie: if an `EditText` is the first thing focused).  To do that, I put this in `onCreate()` method of Activity:

```
 this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: Note that it also works for other view parts, e.g. an EditText :)
Then you would change the following line: `imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);`

Answer (score 57):

**Dont forget to use try catch blog because in case when your keyboard not open and if you use key key board hide code app will crash**

```
try {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

Comment: by far the most simple and elegant solution

Comment: Most ellegant, generic and simple solution, i love it

Answer (score 15):

You can hide the keyboard using the following code, probably on the **Button click Event :**

```
//================ Hide Virtual Key Board When  Clicking==================//

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow("Your Button/EditText Object".getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);

//======== Hide Virtual Keyboard =====================//
```

Answer (score 10):

```
edittext.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Comment: Underrated answer

Answer (score 9):

If the problem is on an activity simply the following will work:

```
    try {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

else if the code is required in a fragment do the following

```
    try {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

This will handle the hiding of keyboard on a button click or any other event as deemed specific when written within the event block.

Answer (score 4):

For the record and based in the answers of @burmat and @Prashant Maheshwari Andro

Let's say that you call the click button as follow.  where buttonAndroidLogin_button is the Button object.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // your code...
    buttonAndroidLogin_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hideKeyboard((Button)v);
            // ....
} // end onCreate
```

On the activity, you must set the next method

```
public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    } catch(Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

**It hides the input using the same button**, so we don't need any linear layout, text view or any other arbitrary control.  Also, the code is reusable for more buttons.

Answer (score 3):

You use this code

```
// Check if no view has focus:
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**IN KOTLIN :**

**In your `fragment` :**

**Create extension like this :**

```
fun Fragment.hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = context?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(requireView().windowToken, 0)
}
```

Then use it like this :

```
hideKeyboard()
```

**In your `activity` :**

**Create extension like this :**

```
fun AppCompatActivity.hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.window.attributes.token, 0)
}
```

Then use it like this :

```
   hideKeyboard()
```

Comment: did not work for me, whereas using the layout to fetch the windowToken did

Comment: What did u mean about windowToken?!

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(rootView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is to remove keyboard from screen on Fragment.

**The Code:**

```
try {
  InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Objects.requireNonNull(requireActivity().getCurrentFocus()).getWindowToken(), 0);
} catch (Exception e) {
  Log.d("PROFILE KEYBOARD ERROR", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).